# Make a jquery icon visible using on keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, hidden, onkeyup

Stumped at this part. I have a simple html input, and a jquery ui icon. What I want to do is have the icon hidden untill a "keyup" event of some sort is fired on the html input. Currently have the css property of the icon set to  `display:none;`, but how would I use javascript to display this after some text is put into the html input?

--Here's my code

```
<input id="solo1" /> <div id="saveButton" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title="Save" style="float:left; display:none; height:20px;" ><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below

```
$("#solo1").keypress(function(){
    $("#saveButton").show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Javascript, or jQuery...first, a Javascript example:

```
<input id="solo1" onKeyUp="document.getElementById('saveButton').style.display = 'block';" />
```

Preferably, in jQuery, and this is all Javascript now:

```
$("#solo1").keyup(function(){
    $("#saveButton").show();
});
```